# Return value of 'AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors' is not used

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to track the process of initializing an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and stuck in here, the call stack is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcOya.png)

in files AnnotationConfigUtils.java,

```
    public static void registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(registry, null);
    }

    public static Set<BeanDefinitionHolder> registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(
            BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, @Nullable Object source) {
...
        return beanDefs;
    }
```

as you can see clearly, the return value is not used by registerAnnotationConfigProcessors, then what's the use of this return value?

I have tried to see the difference if I just skip all the code in 'public static Set registerAnnotationConfigProcessors', but still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You use very strange terminology. A return value is never caught - Exceptions are caught. Return values are either used or not used.

In your specific example, the name of the methods (`registerAnnotationConfigProcessors`) says that they register some annotation config processors. That is the main purpose of these methods and is a so called "side effect": they change the `BeanDefinitionRegistry` that you pass in without necessarily returning anything.

The second method (`registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, @Nullable Object source)`) additionally returns something.

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.25/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigUtils.html#registerAnnotationConfigProcessors-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns: a Set of BeanDefinitionHolders, containing all bean definitions that have actually been registered by this call

A caller of this method might take that result for further processing. But the method `registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)` has no use for that result and therefore simply ignores it.